# Ordem dos controles causa "System.NullReferenceException"

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou a fazer uns testes iniciais com o WPF e surgiu-me esta dúvida.

Não dá erro:

```
<DockPanel Margin="5">
    <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" />
    <Slider x:Name="mySlider" Width="300" SmallChange="1" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" ValueChanged="mySlider_ValueChanged" Minimum="1" />
</DockPanel>

private void mySlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e) 
{ 
    myTextBox.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(mySlider.Value)).ToString(); 
}
```

Por outro lado, trocando a ordem dos controles obtenho:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   mySlider_error.exe but was not handled in user code

Dá erro:

```
    <DockPanel Margin="5">
        <Slider x:Name="mySlider" Width="300" SmallChange="1" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" ValueChanged="mySlider_ValueChanged" Minimum="1" />
        <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" />
    </DockPanel>
```

Sei que posso resolver facilmente este cenário usando, por exemplo:

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" Text="{Binding ElementName=mySlider,Path=Value}" />
```

Apenas pretendo saber porque razão é lançada a exceção?

Comment: Poste o código do: `mySlider_ValueChanged`

Comment: O colega @rubStackOverflow tem toda a razão: poste o código! A minha *suposição* é que esse código, por se tratar de um manipulador de evento, é executado ao menos uma vez quando o objeto `mySlider` é criado. Se esse código tiver/fizer uma referência ao objeto `myTextBox`, a ordem de criação certamente importa.

Comment: Sim faz referência ao myTextbox.

Comment: o que tem no seu mySlider_ValueChanged?

Comment: private void mySlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            myTextBox.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(mySlider.Value)).ToString();
        }

Comment: Você já viu o que esta passando nisso `(Convert.ToInt32(mySlider.Value)).ToString();` para que você converte para int e depois para string?

Comment: Não tenho que converter para string para guardar em Text?

Answer (score 1):

Eu acabei por resolver isto desta forma:

```
    private void atualizarValores_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(textBoxProduto == null))
            textBoxProduto.Text = (int.Parse(textBoxMultiplicador.Text) * int.Parse(textBoxMultiplicando.Text)).ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Durante a construção do componente Slider no load da tela o seu valor é setado com o valor padrão, ao fazer isso, o evento mySlider_ValueChanged é disparado e como o myTextBox ainda não foi construído ele é nulo.

Uma solução seria algo assim:

```
    private bool carregamentoCompleto = false;

    private void mySlider_ValueChanged(object sender,RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        if(carregamentoCompleto)
        {
            myTextBox.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(mySlider.Value)).ToString();
        }
    }

    private void MeuWindows_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        carregamentoCompleto = true;
        myTextBox.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(mySlider.Value)).ToString();
    }
```